# Cannot invoke init with an argument list of type NSURLRequest

Tags: swift, parse-platform, nsurl

In the line that starts with **NSURLConnection**, I get the error: "Cannot invoke init with an argument list of type @value NSURLRequest"

Can it have something do with an error in my parse database? this is the first time I have tried working with parse (first time trying to code with an database, I'm following a tutorial)

This is my code in which my function gives me this error:

```
  override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, object: PFObject?) -> PFTableViewCell? {



    var cell:CatsTableViewCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier) as? CatsTableViewCell

    if(cell == nil) {
        cell = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("CatsTableViewCell", owner: self, options: nil)[0] as? CatsTableViewCell
    }

    if let pfObject = object {
        cell?.catNameLabel?.text = pfObject["name"] as? String

        var votes:Int? = pfObject["votes"] as? Int
        if votes == nil {
            votes = 0
        }
        cell?.catVotesLabel?.text = "\(votes!) votes"

        var credit:String? = pfObject["cc_by"] as? String
        if credit != nil {
            cell?.catCreditLabel?.text = "\(credit!) / CC 2.0"

        }
        cell?.catImageView?.image = nil
        if var urlString:String? = pfObject["url"] as? String {
            var url:NSURL? = NSURL(string: urlString!)

            if var url:NSURL? = NSURL(string: urlString!) {
                var error:NSError?
                var request:NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url!, cachePolicy: NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReturnCacheDataElseLoad, timeoutInterval: 5.0)

                NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().cancelAllOperations()

                NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(), completionHandler: {
                    (response:NSURLResponse!, imageData:NSData!, error:NSError!) -> Void in

                    cell?.catImageView?.image = UIImage(data: imageData)

                })
            }
        }
    }


    return cell    }
```

Comment: don't cancel all operations on the main queue...

Comment: Did you figure this out? Let us know! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The signature of `NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest` is

```
class func sendAsynchronousRequest(_ request: NSURLRequest,
                         queue queue: NSOperationQueue,
             completionHandler handler: (NSURLResponse?,
                                        NSData?,
                                        NSError?) -> Void)
```

all return parameters are optionals.

By the way: The annotations in the optional binding lines are confusing. If the binding succeeds the value is a non-optional. And use `let` rather than `var` in most of the cases for example

```
if let urlString = pfObject["url"] as? String {

  if let url  = NSURL(string: urlString) {
  var error: NSError?
  let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url, cachePolicy: NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReturnCacheDataElseLoad, timeoutInterval: 5.0)
...
```

And, finally, **do not call asynchronous tasks in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`**.

Comment: unfortunately I have no idea where to call the asynchronous task then.

In my tutorial I'm following it says this about the code:

  "technically we rework the Parse url column into an instance of type NSURL.

We use that to start an asynchronous NSURLConnection on the main operation queue, which downloads the image as an NSData object. When the downloading has finished, a closure gets executed. It assigns the data from the download to a UIImage, which gets assigned to the image property of catImageView."

Comment: First update the model (the items in the array of the table view data source) then update the view (call `reloadData()`)

Comment: do you mind taking discussing/helping this further in a chat? I understand I have started with a tutorial  way ahead of my skills. However, I'm so close to the finishing line that I rather see it through. But to be fairly honest I just got more confused by your comment, which hinted me this tutorial is too advanced for me, right now.

Comment: no offense but there are hundreds of tutorials how to populate a table view in iOS. The basic code pattern is always the same

Comment: I have looked for a solution all day, and really been trying not to comment here. But I haven't found any solution. Would you mind explaining what is wrong with my code in a more easier way, for a person like me who just started with swift and Xcode. (I understand I started with a way too advanced tutorial, but this is the last step), so I really want to see it done. @vadian